SE image host -- bitmap extension
Funny, uploading a somewhat less traditional format, direct from file (drag and drop), I obtained this:

The actual image resides at https://i.sstatic.net/IYK4JzFW.png and it seems it just wasn't renamed automatically.

I don't think the bmp format is supported. I searched the entire main meta for information about this, but it isn't clearly mentioned anywhere what formats are officially supported (and they changed the uploader recently, so the information is currently scarce). In any case, posting this on the main meta would certainly get more maningful answers and, possibly, direct reactions from the SE dev team.

Good idea, link here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399431/image-host-bitmap-compatibility

This is not the expected behavior. A fix for bmp images is coming. In the meantime your workaround by changing to png works.
